# Adding column in a dataframe with 0,1 values based on another column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the example dataframe created below:

```
   Name  Age
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
```

I  want to add another column 'Checks' and get the values in it as 0 or 1 if the list check contain s the value as `check=['nick']`

I have tried the below code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
 
check = ['nick']
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

df['Checks'] = np.where(df['Name']== check[], 1, 0)

#print dataframe.
print(df)
print(check)
```

Comment: use isin since check is a list `np.where(df['Name'].isin(check), 1, 0)` or `df['Name'].isin(check).astype(int)`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values for detailed info

Answer (score 2):

[str.containts](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
phrase = ['tom', 'nick']
df['check'] = df['Name'].str.contains('|'.join(phrase))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
check = ['nick']
df['check'] = df['Name'].isin(check).astype(int)
```

output:

```
   Name  Age  check
0   tom   10      0
1  nick   15      1
2  juli   14      0
```